# Leading space removal ruins code formatting when using SE Android App?

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

On my Galaxy Nexus, if I post or edit a question using the official Android app, and that question starts with a code block, the formatting is ruined due to the removal of leading spaces.

You can see the result for yourself:

[image: Code block loses formatting]

The bottom half (1) is the original post, and the top half (2) is the result of my edit. All I did was add the `c++` tag to the post.

I apologize if this is a known bug, but I was unable to find anything similar.

Answer (score 3):

*Fantastic* catch! This is fixed in the next app update (which should be coming sometime... soon? I don't have a definitive timeline at the moment). The issue was an errant `.toString().trim()` when sending data to the API, the trim is best practice for tags (since it loads the tags as a space-delimited string then splits them up into an array) but not necessary (and incorrect!) for the body.